# Will two different subgroups of a Galois group have different fixed fields?

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I'm trying to figure out will two different subgroups of a Galois group have different fixed fields. Intuitively, I think they have the same fixed fields. But I am not sure. Anyone has ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your field extension is Galois, then there is a one-to-one correspondence between subgroups of the Galois group and the intermediate fields. The correspondence associates a subgroup to its fixed field. This is called "The Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory".

So different subgroups will have different fixed fields.

However if your extension is not Galois, this is bijection does not hold.

For example: $Aut(\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})/\mathbb{Q}) = \{identity\}$, but there are two intermediary fields in this extension, namely $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$ and $\mathbb{Q}$ themselves.

Comment: It convinces me. But can you provide a more specific example? I'm struggled here.

Comment: This should be more helpful than any tiny examples I could type up.
[Galois Correspondence -Keith Conrad](http://www.math.uconn.edu/~kconrad/blurbs/galoistheory/galoiscorr.pdf)

Comment: To clarify, for *any* finite subgroup $G \subset \operatorname{Aut}(F)$, for a field $F$, the fixed subfield $F^G \subset F$ defines a Galois extension. So it is indeed *always* true, for finite groups, that distinct subgroups define distinct fixed fields. The failure of Galois correspondence in general happens in the other direction - distinct subfields don't always define distinct automorphism groups.